# Game Maker - Load a string from file?

Tags: game-maker, gml

I want to give a unit a random name. I was thinking I could supply my game with a txt file containing a long list of names, and then choosing one at random. How would I go about doing this in gml?

Answer (score 2):

Many ways are possible here. For example:

Read all names (only once, when game starts; each name must be placed at new line):

```
var file = file_text_open_read("names.txt");
var i = 0;

while !file_text_eof(file)
{
    global.names[i++] = file_text_read_string(file);
    file_text_readln(file);
}
```

Then you can get random name like this:

```
var name = names[irandom(array_length_1d(global.names) - 1)];
```